# how do I make CMake wait for ExternalProject_Add finish?

Tags: c++, cmake

Project structure:

```
rocksdb/CMakeLists.txt
...
rocksdb/third-party/CMakeLists.txt
rocksdb/third-party/snappy
```

In side `rocksdb/third-party/CMakeLists.txt`, I added snappy as external project as below:

```
# Snappy                                                                                                                                            
IF(WITH_SNAPPY)                                                                                                                                     
  FIND_PACKAGE(snappy QUIET)                                                                                                                        
  IF (NOT snappy_FOUND)                                                                                                                             
    MESSAGE("[/third-party] snappy not found, build target")                                                                                
    ExternalProject_Add(snappy-project                                                                                                              
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/snappy                                                                                               
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND mkdir -p build                                                                                                            
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1                                                                                                                           
        BUILD_COMMAND cd build && cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -DSNAPPY_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DHAVE_LIBLZO2=OFF && make -j 10    
        INSTALL_COMMAND cd build && ls -l && make install && cd ../ && rm -rf build)                                                                
    ADD_LIBRARY(snappy STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)                                                                                                      
    ADD_DEPENDENCIES(snappy snappy-project)                                                                                                         
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(snappy PROPERTIES                                                                                                         
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libsnappy.a                                                                                       
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)                                                                                            
  ELSE()                                                                                                                                            
    MESSAGE("[/third-party] snappy exist, not build")                                                                                       
  ENDIF()                                                                                                                                           
ENDIF()
```

And in the top level CMakeLists.txt I use

```
  add_subdirectory(third-party)
  if(WITH_SNAPPY)
    add_definitions(-DSNAPPY)
    if(NOT TARGET snappy)
        find_package(snappy QUIET)
        if(NOT snappy_FOUND)
            message("[] snappy find package failed!")
        else()
            message("[] snappy find package success!")
        endif()
    else()
        message("[] snappy target existed!")
    endif()
    get_target_property(snappy_INCLUDE_DIR snappy INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    include_directories(${snappy_INCLUDE_DIR})
    message("snappy include dir : ${snappy_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    list(APPEND THIRDPARTY_LIBS snappy)
  endif()
```

to make snappy target availiable.

But the problem is, when I use `make -j 100` to build the rocksdb project, I turns out the snappy is not build at first.

Can anyone help to resolve the problem? thanks!

== EDIT ==
This is how I consume the snappy library:

```
add_library(${ROCKSDB_STATIC_LIB} STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${ROCKSDB_STATIC_LIB} ${THIRDPARTY_LIBS} ${SYSTEM_LIBS})
```

I don't see any problem here, this is really wired!

Comment: Since you have added dependency between IMPORTED library (`snappy`) and external project (`snappy-project`), the external project should be built before any target, which links with your IMPORTED library or otherwise depends (via `add_dependencies`) from it. In other words: Your setup looks correct. If `snappy` library is consumed correctly, then build order should also be correct. But since you don't show the code which consumes the library, we cannot tell whether it is correct or not. Please, show more code.

Comment: BTW, you may add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE` to your `ExternalProject_Add` call, so external project won't be built until some other target requires it. Such way you may check whether you correctly specified dependency from external project even without the parallel build (which is quite non-deterministic).

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev, thanks for your comment, but I can't find any problem with the comsume CMake code.